# Why are my LINQ queries returning zero?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I am new to LINQ and no matter how hard I try to get these two queries to work I always end up with zero as the result. I've tried everything to calculate the business days in a month and the total number of days. MDate is binded to a datepicker, BusinessDays to a textbox and TotalDaysInMonth to another textbox.

Can someone please help me fix these queries to show up the right values for a selected month? (e.g. September: 20 BusinessDays, 30 TotalDays)

```
public class LocationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public LocationViewModel()
    {    
        SetBusinessDays();
        SetTotalDaysInMonth();
    }

    public DateTime mDate = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime MDate
    {
        get { return mDate; }
        set
        {
            if (value == mDate)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                mDate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MDate");

                SetBusinessDays();
                SetTotalDaysInMonth();
            }
        }
    }

    int _businessDays;

    public int BusinessDays
    {
        get { return _businessDays; }
        set
        {
            _businessDays = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BusinessDays");
        }
    }

    int _totalDaysInMonth;

    public int TotalDaysInMonth
    {
        get { return _totalDaysInMonth; }
        set
        {
            _totalDaysInMonth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TotalDaysInMonth");
        }
    }


    private void SetBusinessDays()

    {
        int BusinessDays = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(MDate.Year, MDate.Month))
                            .Select(day => new DateTime(MDate.Year, MDate.Month, day))
                            .Count(d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday &&
                                        d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday);
    }

    private void SetTotalDaysInMonth()
    {
        int TotalDaysInMonth = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(MDate.Year, MDate.Month))
                            .Select(day => new DateTime(MDate.Year, MDate.Month, day))
                            .Count();
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're setting local variables, not your properties.

Comment: remove the `int` declaration in your local variables.

Comment: I get 22. [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZNA9eJ). The problem isn't your LINQ.

Comment: As @Ephraim said, you have `int BusinessDays = ...` and `int TotalDaysInMonth = ...` in `SetBusinessDays` and `SetTotalDaysInMonth`. You are basically declaring a local variable instead of assigning the values to `BusinessDays` and `TotalDaysInMonth` properties. Remove the `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside both of your methods you are declaring a local variable rather then setting your property. In C# you don't need to specify the type of whenever accessing a property. Remove both `int` literals inside your methods.

Comment: That was it. I can't believe I couldn't spot it. Thank you so much, you saved me a lot of time and effort. Have a great day Jevgeni!